# Why is DropBox not included in sync indicator in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, indicator, dropbox

Why is Drop Box not included in sync indicator manu in ubuntu 13.04? Ubuntu one is, but there is no Drop Box. Now I have two indicators. One for Ubuntu One and one for Drop Box. Is there a way to have just one? If not, is it going to be possible in the future?

Comment: How do you dare to point this question as duplicated of another which has no answer yet and it is related to a different version? Nice...

Comment: Because it's the same question. I removed the version from it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because the upstream DropBox code has not been changed to support the new sync indicator. Or, if it has already, you are running an older version and need to upgrade to the newer version which does.

Comment: The version I have is 1.4.0-3. I installed it through the ubuntu software center. Should I add PPA and upgrade it?